# Reducing PCollection after GroupByKey

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to produce a simple customer summary based on transactional data.  For example, given a target transaction type, how many transactions occurred and what was the total amount?

Example of the raw input:

```
custid  desc        amount
111     coffee      3.50
111     grocery     23.00
333     coffee      4.00
222     gas station 32.00
222     gas station 55.50
333     coffee      3.00
```

Example of desired output:

```
custid nbr_coffee amt_coffee nbr_gas_station amt_gas_station
111    1          3.50       0               0.00
222    0          0          2               87.50
333    2          7.00       0               0
```

My target runner will be Dataflow (but currently using DirectRunner for testing).

Here is a code snippet of what I have:

```
def categorize_coffee(transaction):

    if transaction['trx_desc'] == 'coffee':
        transaction['coffee'] = True
    else:
        transaction['coffee'] = False

    return transaction

def categorize_gas_station(transaction):

    if transaction['trx_desc'] == 'gas station':
        transaction['gas_station'] = True
    else:
        transaction['gas_station'] = False

    return transaction

def summarize_coffee(grouping):

    key, values = grouping
    values = list(values)

    nbr = 0
    amt = 0

    for d in values:
        if d['coffee'] == True:
            nbr+=1
            amt+=d['amount']

    ret_val = {}
    ret_val['cust'] = d['cust']
    ret_val['nbr_coffee'] = nbr
    ret_val['amt_coffee'] = amt

    return ret_val

def summarize_gas_station(grouping):

    key, values = grouping
    values = list(values)

    nbr = 0
    amt = 0

    for d in values:
        if d['gas_station'] == True:
            nbr += 1
            amt += d['amount']

    ret_val = {}
    ret_val['cust'] = d['cust']
    ret_val['nbr_gas_station'] = nbr
    ret_val['amt_gas_station'] = amt

    return ret_val

def create_dict(row):

    vars = row.split(',')
    return {'cust': vars[0], 'trx_desc': str(vars[1]), 'amount': float(vars[2])}

with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

    categorized_trx = (
        p | 'get data' >> beam.io.ReadFromText('./test.csv')
        | beam.Map(create_dict)
        | beam.Map(categorize_coffee)
        | beam.Map(categorize_gas_station)
        | beam.Map(lambda trx: (trx['cust'], trx))
        | beam.GroupByKey()
    )

    coffee_trx = (categorized_trx | beam.Map(summarize_coffee))

    gas_station_trx = (categorized_trx | beam.Map(summarize_gas_station))

    result = (coffee_trx, gas_station_trx) | beam.Flatten()
```

The actual results right now is:

```
{'amt_coffee': 7.0, 'cust': u'333', 'nbr_coffee': 2}
{'amt_coffee': 0, 'cust': u'222', 'nbr_coffee': 0}
{'amt_coffee': 3.5, 'cust': u'111', 'nbr_coffee': 1}
{'nbr_gas_station': 0, 'cust': u'333', 'amt_gas_station': 0}
{'nbr_gas_station': 2, 'cust': u'222', 'amt_gas_station': 87.5}
{'nbr_gas_station': 0, 'cust': u'111', 'amt_gas_station': 0}
```

There is no flattening or joining as I would have expected.  I'm new to Beam - not sure if I am understanding how to approach this problem correctly so would love some insights.

Comment: Although different question the answer here around combiners should help:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55445851/how-can-i-stop-the-extra-repetition-in-the-return-yield-while-still-keeping-the/55447288#55447288

Comment: @RezaRokni This question allows me to see how I could combine values if they were keyed as ('nbr_coffee', 1).    However in my case I have ('333', ('nbr_coffee', 1)).  How would I combine per key per customer?  Also, I am going to have multiple combiners as sometimes I need counts and other times i need amounts - would this lead me back to my problem of combining two collections?

Comment: Flatten will just merge all results into a single PCollection. To join them you can use CoGroupByKey with `cust` as the key https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#core-beam-transforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
...

def summarize_coffee(grouping):

    ...

    return (d['cust'], ret_val)


def summarize_gas_station(grouping):

    ...

    return (d['cust'], ret_val)

...

def processJoin(row):
    (customer, data) = row
    coffee_trx=data['coffee_trx']
    gas_station_trx=data['gas_station_trx']
    return (customer, coffee_trx, gas_station_trx)

result = ({coffee_trx: coffee_trx, gas_station_trx: gas_station_trx}
         | 'Group' >> beam.CoGroupByKey()    
         | 'Reshape' >> beam.Map(processJoin)
         | 'Unwind' >> beam.FlatMap(lambda x: x)
         )
```

Answer (score 0):

Beam offers [Combine](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#combine) transform that should allow your to combine elements of a PCollection. Looks like for your use-case you can use [Combine.perKey()](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Combine.java#L144) to combine keyed elements of a PCollection based on the key. As the combine function, you can either provide a function or implement [CombineFn](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Combine.java#L333).

Comment: Are you able to provide a specific example using combine that would help me?  Combiners were recommended in a comment above and I can't see how it would be use to achieve my desired output.